# How do you paint a specific line in a richTextBox C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, paint

Given this text in a `RichTextBox`:

```
str1
str2
str3
```

I don't know the length of all of them.
How can I paint the first line with green color and the third with blue?
I read a bit of the `SelectionColor` but I don't want that the line will be marked.
There's another way? Or maybe that way (with `SelectionColor`) but can you explain me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following ways:

- giving it's value like this:

  ```
  richTextBox1.Find("str1"); 
  richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
  richTextBox1.Find("str3");
  richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
  ```
- the other way like this:

  ```
  richTextBox1.Select(0, 3);//Select text within 0 and 3
  richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
  richTextBox1.Select(9, 12);
  richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
  ```

  **Edit:** To hide the selection add this line to end of your code :

  ```
  richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
  ```

Comment: Thanks!! It work, but there is a way that I can hide the selection?

Comment: Done, can you please answer my second question?

Comment: To hide the selection check my updated answer.`richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);`

Comment: Is it necessary to select prior to coloring text?

Comment: @theMayer yes  it is.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know the length of all of them.

Here's an alternate approach:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorLine(0, Color.Green);
        ColorLine(2, Color.Blue);
    }

    private void ColorLine(int line, Color clr)
    {
        int index = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
        int length = richTextBox1.Lines[line].Length;
        richTextBox1.Select(index, length);
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = clr;
        richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: If you're searching for a specific string, then want to color that line, store the returned index from [RichTextBox.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfcsf75k(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass that to [RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex(v=vs.110).aspx).  Now you can use the line number in my code above.